# Handling NA values with pickerInput filter

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinywidgets

I am working on a shiny app that has a reactive df which I am using to render a dt data table. My issue is that on my sidebar pickerInput filters I am using:

`choices = unique(COLUMN_NAME)`

When there is `NA` values in the column that gets turned into "NA" on the filter so when I use:

`filter(COLUMN_NAME %in% input$column_name)`

In the reactive df the NA values do not filter correctly. What is the best way around this? Should I recode any NA values to a string or should I work around fixing the sidebar filter so that NA filters to truly NA values?

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible example so that people can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Based on what you have said though, the recoding NA values as characters may be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I think much better would be to leave `NA` as a special case, i.e. treating it as missing value, not `character`. This is because in R (and you compute in R) `NA` is a well-established object, so you may get many advantages (like speed) when leaving it in a data frame as `NA` (missing value).

But that's true, that JavaScript doesn't have such an construct as `NA`, so we end up with character type:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(c(1, NA, 2))
#> [1,"NA",2]
```

Assuming that:

- you are working with data.frame (you want to filter data.frame) and you use `dplyr::filter` (very important as by the default, if you filter by known value, missing values are dropped, different than in e.g. `c(1, NA)[c(1, NA) == 1]`, where NA values will be preserved).

You can try something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

is_val <- function(value, set) {
  if (all(value == "NA")) {
    is.na(set)
  } else {
    if (any(value == "NA")) {
      set %in% value | is.na(set)
    } else {
      set %in% value
    }
  }
}

choices <- data.frame(col = c(1, NA, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2))


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("column_name", "Choose", choices = unique(choices$col), multiple = TRUE),
  tableOutput("display_val")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$display_val <- renderTable({
    req(input$column_name)
    choices |> 
      filter(is_val(input$column_name, col))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The crucial is function `is_val` of course, which has different modes depending of if the `"NA`" was picked up by user or not. This code could be a little simpler if `pickerInput` won't have `multiple = TRUE`.